# Docusign Rest API CarbonCopy Not Working

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send a Document for signature using Docusign (Using RestAPI), It has one recipient as a Signer and one as Carbon Copy. I have pasted the JSON below  and also I get a success message when calling the Rest API in the demo environment.

However the Recipient designated as CarbonCopy never gets the email, The Signer do recieves the email from Docusign

```
"emailSubject" : "This is the Subject of the Message",
  "emailBlurb" : "This is the Body of the message",
  "recipients" : {
    "signers" : [ {
      "routingOrder" : "1",
      "name" : "Signer 1",
      "email" : "signer1@gmail.com",
      "recipientId" : "1",
      "tabs" : {
        "signHereTabs" : [ {
          "anchorString" : "By:",
          "anchorXOffset" : "0",
          "anchorYOffset" : "0",
          "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : "true",
          "anchorUnits" : "inches"
        } ]
      }
    } ],
    "carbonCopies" : [ {
      "routingOrder" : "2",
      "recipientId" : "2",
      "name" : "Carbon Copy1",
      "email" : "carboncopy1@gmail.com"
    } ]
  },
  "documents" : [ {
    "name" : "document.pdf",
    "documentId" : "1",
    "bytes" : "document Bytes go here - Omitted to make it readable"
  } ],
  "status" : "sent"
}
```

Success Message Recieved

```
{  "envelopeId": "95c0cd64-7b4e-4d98-ad9c-ae74c08cf7f9",  "uri": "/envelopes/95c0cd64-7b4e-4d98-ad9c-ae74c08cf7f9",  "statusDateTime": "2015-10-19T21:00:30.7100000Z",  "status": "sent"}
```

Comment: You have the CC in routing order 2. Has the signer completed the envelope? If not, then the CC will not get the email until it's their step in the routing order.

Comment: Yes , I did change the routing order of 1 and as mentioned by you , that is exactly the behaviour I am getting , how do I have the carbon copy also get the email when the document is sent out. Currently the routing order for both of them is set to 1 , but the carbon copy only gets the document when it is complete

Comment: If i put the routing order of both as 1 I get this error {  "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS",  "message": "The specified envelope has duplicate recipients."}

Comment: When you set both to `routingOrder = 1` if it is the same exact recipient (i.e. email, name, and recipientId) then you will the duplicate recipients error.  Is it the same recipient you are testing with?

Comment: So your goal is for the cc person to get the unsigned doc first, then the second person signs?

Comment: Yes and I did solve the problem having the carbon copy routing order always higher than the signers, so in the above JSON just reversed the routing order and it worked for me

Comment: From your comment, it sounds like you solved your problem. Please answer your own question (in the answer box below) so others can benefit from your experience. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes and I did solve the problem having the carbon copy routing order always higher than the signers, so in the above JSON just reversed the routing order and it worked for me